# rearranging and or rejecting an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array that is transmitted to me, when I receive good data it looks like this:

```
byte[] buffer = { 0xaa, 0x02, 0x47, 0xf0, 0x79, 0x00, 0x45, 0x2c, 0x12, 0x20, 0xc6, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x2d, 0xb2, 0x55 };
```

However I wanted to rearrange the array just in case it doesn't come in  correctly. for instance:

```
byte[] buffer = { 0x02, 0x47, 0xf0, 0x79, 0x00, 0x45, 0x2c, 0x12, 0x20, 0xc6, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x2d, 0xb2, 0x55, 0xaa };
```

The message needs to start with 0xaa and end with 0x55. in this scenario it is 0xaa is at the end.

Bonus: how would I reject a message if say a special or junk character was accidentally transmitted?

I have tried using

```
array.copy(buffer, index, new_buffer, buffer.length-index);
```

as well but it didnt work. This is what I have so far:

```
         byte[] adjusted_buffer = new byte[16];
        //byte[] buffer = { 0xaa, 0x02, 0x47, 0xf0, 0x79, 0x00, 0x45, 0x2c, 0x12, 0x20, 0xc6, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x2d, 0xb2, 0x55 };
        byte[] buffer = { 0x02, 0x47, 0xf0, 0x79, 0x00, 0x45, 0x2c, 0x12, 0x20, 0xc6, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x2d, 0xb2, 0x55, 0xaa };

        if (buffer[0].Equals(0xaa) && buffer[15].Equals(0x55) && buffer.Length.Equals(16))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("arranged");
        }
        else
        {
            int index = Array.IndexOf<byte>(buffer, 0xaa);
            if (buffer[index - 1].Equals(0x55) && buffer.Length.Equals(16))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                {
                    adjusted_buffer[i] = buffer[index + i];
                }

                Console.WriteLine(adjusted_buffer);
            }
            else
            {
                index = (byte) Array.IndexOf(buffer, 0xaa, index);
                if (buffer[index - 1].Equals(0x55) && buffer.Length.Equals(16))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                    {
                        adjusted_buffer[i] = buffer[index + i];
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("rearranged again");
```

Comment: This is a little weird, if you're receiving data trough TCP, Serial, whatever, the start and end bytes exist precisely to do a fast check whether data arrived correctly or not, checksums as well. How can you be sure that everything is there to re-arrange?

Comment: I have a check that I am getting 16 bytes. The message comes in through serial. When I user CuteCom on linux I get get data consistently, on c#, I've lost packets. Sometimes I get 16 bytes, othertimes I don't. However it hits pretty fast though, I don't go more than 3 seconds with out a new message.

Comment: Is it TCP? UDP? Serial? With size you can have your first check, but if you receive a message with the required size where first and last byte are in the middle of the array, how do you know how to arrange it? Every byte might be in the wrong position.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start off with declaring some constants...

```
const byte START = 0x02;
const byte END = 0x55;
const int SIZE = 16;
```

Then we can deal with the incoming messages...

```
var buffer = /* set incoming buffer value */;

if (buffer[0] != START)
{
    var fixedBuffer = new List<byte> { START };

    fixedBuffer.AddRange(removeFirstInstanceFromBuffer(buffer, START));

    buffer = fixedBuffer.ToArray();
}

if (buffer[buffer.Length - 1] != END)
{
    var fixedBuffer = new List<byte>();

    fixedBuffer.AddRange(removeFirstInstanceFromBuffer(buffer, END));
    fixedBuffer.Add(END);

    buffer = fixedBuffer.ToArray();
}

// wherever you want to have helper methods

private byte[] removeFirstInstanceFromBuffer(byte[] bytes, byte b)
{
    var idx = bytes.ToList().IndexOf(bytes.First(x => x == b));
    var truncated = new List<byte>();

    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) if (i != idx) truncated.Add(bytes[i]);

    return truncated.ToArray();
}
```

Then if you want to throw out junk characters and such, simply declare an array of the junk characters you want cleared and use the utility method below as follows...

```
var bytesToRemove = new List<byte>();

foreach (var b in buffer)
{
    if (JUNK_ARRAY.Contains(b)) bytesToRemove.Add(b);
}

foreach (var b in bytesToRemove)
{
    buffer = removeFirstInstanceFromBuffer(buffer, b);
}
```

**NOTE:** If your byte stream isn't coming through correctly, you might have bigger problems and just rearranging it might be a bad idea. Data like this can come from a motor or a sensor so if it's malformed, you'd just be ignoring the issue. The code given above will make sure your message is correct byte by byte and throw an error if there's a junk byte somewhere in the stream. And if you're losing packets, you also have a network issue to look into, not solely a programming one.

**EDIT:** Misunderstood request, fixed code to solve the requested problem as explained by @tweellt.

**EDIT 2:** Fixed helper method to find the index properly.

Comment: I don't quite follow this code... how would this work with different messages? I think his point is to receive all kind of messages with a certain size, start and end byte.

Comment: Well, then I misunderstood what he was asking and will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: so in trials the shift only occurred once. I've ran the trial 6 times and it always comes up correctly. So I don't know what happened with that failed case.

Comment: If your device is transmitting constantly and you're listening only at certain time periods, it's entirely plausible that a slight delay caused by who knows what hardware issue, or firmware glitch resulted in a shifted byte stream. If you keep running your listener long enough, you might encounter some way to replicating said shift. But here's the code to shift it back, although keep in mind that if you have another `0x02` or `0x55` other than in the beginning or the end in one of your messages, you may still end up with a bad byte stream so be sure to validate your input thoroughly.

Comment: Technically the start of a valid message is 0xaa. I'm I safe to assume that changing START to 0xaa will still perform correctly?

Comment: Oh yeah, absolutely. START can be anything you want as long as it's a valid byte value.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the 'removeFirstInstanceFromBuffer' method. What are you referencing to get 'bytes.IndexOf(bytes.First(x => x == b));' to work? According to the error I am getting IndexOf is not an overload method. EDIT:There might be something wrong with that method entirely, you are missing  something when you call IndexOf.

Comment: IndexOf is [a method for arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns the index of the first instance of a particular item. Did you include `System.Linq`, which has a `First()` extension method?

Comment: @gfish3000 Yes, I did. At first glance it looks like it would work. `using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Comment: @JonathanNath, ok, I see what the problem was. I didn't convert the array to a `List` first and forgot that IndexOf was a little more complicated than that. I edited the answer accordingly.